# WP - Contact form 7 - Input & Btn next to each other

Tags: wordpress, css-float, contact-form-7

here my website I´m working on: http://www.whatsahoy.com/

My problem: I want the input field next to the button. If I add a float left, it goes next to each other but with a weird `<br>`. And then the whole thing is also on the left. I want it to be in the middle.

Can somebody help me please?! Thank you very much!
Barbara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide you with the best solution, it would be helpful to see the source code of your form. The `<br>` is probably in there somewhere. However, here is my reply based on what I can see. If it does not help, I suggest you update your question.

Adding the following styles to your custom CSS will put the field and button next to eachother until screen width of 767px.

```
.wpcf7-form p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 470px;
    max-width: 95%;
}

.wpcf7-form p br {
    display: none;
}
```

If you would like them next to eachother on smaller screens, you could change the width of the frame. This changes on 767px as set by your theme. I'm not sure this will not have an undesired effect elsewhere on your site, but you could try.

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .et_pb_row {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

However, it then will be crippled on screens as from 600px. It may be better to make the text field smaller then...

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
    .wpcf7 input {
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}
```

You might want to fine tune this a bit, but I hope you get the idea.
GL!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much! 
That worked for a screen with width more than 767px;
Everything is fine, but on smaller devices the forms are not in the middle. Just slightly off. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe... If it is 5% off, but I don't see it... 470px is roughly the width of the text field + button + space in between. It pushes the hidden ajax loader below it. The max 95% width makes sure it does not become wider than the available space around it. The idea was to make sure it does not touch the borders of the screen, but this does not happen anyway, so you could set it to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
display: inline-block !important;
     margin: -8px;
}
form.wpcf7-form.init.mailchimp-ext-0\.5\.55 {
    
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.has-spinner.wpcf7-submit {
    border-radius:0px !important;
    width: 30%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 600px)  {

div#wpcf7-f698-p10-o1 {
    width: 130%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 600px)  {

input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-email.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-email {
    width: 235px;
    }
    form.wpcf7-form.init.mailchimp-ext-0\.5\.55 {
    display: flex !important;
    
 padding-right: 70px;
}}
```